# R: Using only one extrernal vector in as variable in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I receive a warning about using an external vector as a variable in a series of code I have to augment some data and produce plots.

"Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
i Use `all_of(anlyt)` instead of `anlyt` to silence this message.
i See https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html."

I need to replace a ONE variable multiple times in my code for each set of plots and would prefer to re-value a vector each time

```
   v<- DOC .... run scripts
```

then

```
   v<- NH4 .... run scripts
```

repeat

When producing the boxplots I receive the y-axis without a scale since I passed a non variable (I think)
I have seen people using '''aes_string''', but this does not seem to work since only one of my variables is being named by a vector.

```
v <- ('cty')

 plot <- mpg %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x= model, y = v))+
 geom_boxplot()+
 coord_flip()+
 geom_jitter(aes(color = year))
```

I have tried things like paste() or print() without result.

In the end I want the same result as this:

```
 plot <- mpg %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x= model, y = cty))+
 geom_boxplot()+
 coord_flip()+
 geom_jitter(aes(color = year))
```

If I use as.name() and aes_() (thank you, https://rpubs.com/hadley/97970) I this code works.

```
v <- 'cty'
w <- 'model'
plot <- mpg %>% 
ggplot(aes_(x = as.name(w), y = as.name(v)))+
geom_boxplot()+
coord_flip()+
geom_jitter(aes(color = year))
```

It does require using vectors for both x and y variables, I only want to use one on y. Does anyone know a method to use only one external vector???
Thanks yall'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using `sym()` and `!!`:

```
v <- ('cty')
v <- sym(v)
plot <- mpg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= model, y = !!v))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  coord_flip()+
  geom_jitter(aes(color = year))
```

Output:

[image]